# How to bind a command to a control inside control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-7.0

I have a window which has a user control which has a user control which has a button.

The window's `DataContext` is set to a view model. The view model has a method that needs to be called then the button is clicked.

Currently i have commands as dependency props in both user controls.

Then I bind the top control command to the view model in the window..

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Please consider sharing some code to help other help you, and feel free to mask out any sensitive code you don't wish to share with dummy data :)

Comment: Why doesn't the button have the same datacontext as the window?

Comment: Button or user controls don't have knowledge of the window. It is the window or rather view model needs to bind to the button command..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a more elegant way?

You could bind directly to the view model of the parent window:

```
<Button ... Command="{Binding DataContext.WindowViewModelCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Or use an [event aggregator](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) or a messenger to send an event/message to the parent view model in a decoupled way.

Or inject both view models with a shared service and handle the communication between them using this one.

Comment: I kinda wanted for the view model to bind directly to the button command. User control with button can be anywhere. It shouldn't try to bind to the parent.. I'll just expose the button as a public element and subscribe to the click event. Jumping through 50 hoops to be mvvm pure seems wrong to me